# Second AsyncTask never gets called

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have two AsyncTask in my app, MyClientTask and CloseSocket. MyClientTask is to connect to a server and output whatever the server sends in a textview and with a notification, which I press a button that connects and sends a message to the server. It works fine. 
Now, for CloseSocket, I wanted to have a disconnect button that stops the connection. It is set up the exact same way as the connect button. It is a different AsyncTask of course but it is never called. There are no errors. I put a simple System.out when I declare the button to see if its set up correct, which works. I also have a System.out in the "doInBackground" that will let me know if it ever gets called, which it does not. I have

```
 socket.close(), socket.getInputStream().close(), socket.getOutputStream().close()
```

to close the socket, but it doesn't matter because the CloseSocket AsyncTask never gets called.

Also, The server is pinging the app every 10 seconds for testing so I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Please show complete onClick() and CloseSocket code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Honeycomb, AsyncTasks run serially by default, not in parallel. You need to tell it to run on a ThreadPoolExecutor.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this?

Comment: Where are you currently executing your tasks...?